# Angularfire 2 object interpolation doesn't print anything

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I'm trying to show in the view a simple object interpolation.
This is the method:

```
public getStatus(uid: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.db.object(`user_status/${uid}`).valueChanges();
}
```

And this is the interpolation with an existing hardcoded uid using the async pipe:

```
{{(getStatus('fooUid') | async)?.status}}
```

No error and nothing is rendered in the view.

The weirdest part is that if I unwrap the observable in the component with this code the value is correctly logged:

```
this.getStatus('fooUid').pipe(first()).subscribe(res => console.log(res.status));
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What if you do `this.status = this.getStatus('fooUid')` and `{{ (status | async)?.status }}`?

Comment: I can't do that. The interpolation needs to work inside a dynamic ngFor where different ids will be used.

Comment: There may be something else going on because your code as it stands seems to work as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gir7sw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts